# Button shape with Image in Eclipse

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, button

I have made an app in Eclipse and I am weak in finishings. I have a button which has a drawable image and a text(String). I want that button to have rounded edges. But I can use only one drawable command in a button. Is it possible to impart an image in the shape changing xml code for button?

Here is my code for the button :

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/searchbutton"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/match4"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:background="@drawable/buttonimage2"
        android:text="@string/date"
        android:textColor="#000099"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
```

And I can write this xml code to change button shape:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="#000069"
        android:endColor="#ffffff"
        android:angle="180"/>
    <padding android:left="6dp"
        android:top="6dp"
        android:right="6dp"
        android:bottom="6dp" />
    <corners android:radius="30dp" />

</shape>
```

I want this shape with padding and corners.. but the gradient should be replaced by my 'buttonimage2'. I hope I am clear here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `layer-list` for combination of bitmap and drawable. use something like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item android:drawable="@drawable/buttonimage2">
<shape android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="5dp">
  <corners
   android:bottomRightRadius="30dp"
   android:bottomLeftRadius="30dp"
   android:topLeftRadius="30dp"
   android:topRightRadius="30dp"/>
 </shape>
 </item>
</layer-list>
```

and set this drawable to your `Button`

Comment: I m Sorry Maddy. I worked the way you told and the image came to button allright. But not the shape :/
I tried cleaning the project still no luck.

Comment: If you are using image then why don't you create image with required shape.

Comment: I should have tried that before. Thank you so much!

Comment: your welcome. I would appreciate if you could up vote this or accept as ans.

Answer (score 0):

use the below as drawble file,let suppose button_bg.xml

```
 <shape android:shape="rectangle">
     <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"/> --> change any color here accorring to your requirement
         <corners android:bottomLeftRadius="8dp"
                  android:bottomRightRadius="8dp" 
                  android:topLeftRadius="8dp" 
                  android:topRightRadius="8dp"/>

     <stroke android:width="1dp" 
             android:color="#9c9a9b"/> --> change any color here accorring to your requirement
</shape>
```

## here is your button code

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/searchbutton"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/match4"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button_bg"
    android:text="@string/date"
    android:textColor="#000099"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="20sp" />
```

Comment: Where is my buttonimage2.jpg?

android:background="@drawable/buttonimage2" regers to an image buttonimage2 in my drawable folder.